# Deleting the last digit of a textbox that takes only numbers

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a textbox that takes only numbers (0-9).

I want to disable a save button if the user didn't enter anything or removed the existing value. But the button was not disabling even after deleting all digits. then I realized that last digit was always there (in the background). I also implmented CanExecuteChanged!!!

MyView.xaml

```
<TextBox PreviewTextInput="NumberValidationTextBox" 
                     Text="{Binding CarCost, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

<Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
```

Number validation method

```
private void NumberValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
     Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
     e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
}
```

MyViewModel.cs

```
private int _carCost
public int CarCost
{
    get => _carCost;
    set
    {
      _carCost= value;
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CarCost));
    }
}
```

SaveCommand

```
public class SaveSettingsCommand : CommandBase
    {
        private readonly MyViewModel _myViewModel;


        public SaveCommand(MyViewModel MyViewModel)
        {
            _MyViewModel = MyViewModel;
            _MyViewModel.PropertyChanged += OnViewModelPropertyChanged;
        }

        private void OnViewModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(MyViewModel.CarCost))
            {
                OnCanExecuteChanged();  // will call CanExecuteChanged from base
            }
        }

        public override void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if (_MyViewModel.CarCost >0)
            {
                _MyViewModel.SaveSettings();
            }    
        }

        public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            var result= _MyViewModel.CarCost >0;

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why dont you just make a bool property for the validation and bind it to Button's IsEnabled property:

Like this:
   '<Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding 
    Path=IsValidNumber}"/>'

Comment: Still button will be always enabled, as the last digit is not deleting ( even though text box appears empty)

Comment: Can you provide full code sample to reproduce your issue?

Comment: You could also create a bool property and use it as the CommandParameter instead

Comment: You could try to add the MahApps.Metro nuget package to your project. MahApps has a few really usefull control for issues like handling numerical TextBox. Check this one out: 
[NumericUpDown](https://mahapps.com/docs/controls/numericupdown)

Comment: The last value can't be deleted because the produced result string is an empty string, which is not convertible to an int value. Therefore, no value is assigned to the CarCost property and therefore no PropertyChanged event is raised.  Either define your property that binds to the TextBox.Text as string of implement a converter that explicitly converts from string to int. Using a Regex to validate the input is not recommended (in this case). At least use a compiled Regex that you can die in a private field or property.Creating a new Regex instance (same pattern) on every input is too expensive

Comment: To make it clear: the TextBox is cleared but the empty string can't be assigned to an int property. Therefore, the int property will keep the last value value.